# HttpURLConnection Exception?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have wrote a function to read a response from a URL:

```
private static String readResponse(String urlAddress) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }  catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        throw new Exception();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

When I run this on a Samsung Galaxy S7 it works fine but when i run it on an HTC1 i get the following exception:

`Unexpected status line: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

How can it work on one but not the other, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're getting an exception on the server itself. It returned an HTML error page

Comment: Cricket is correct, however he did not tell you how to correct the problem. You can use a browser with a plugin such as https://alternativeto.net/software/postman/ to test a request to your server and monitor what the server sends back. You can then check that android sent a proper request

Comment: so i checked the response in postman. and the response is correct. Could it be the android version that the device is using? the HTC is using Lollipop and the Samsung is using Marshmallow.